# Want to make google map on website seem bigger on Iphone

Tags: iphone, google-maps-api-3, mobile-safari, font-size

I have a google map on my website using google-maps-APIv3. But the Map seems very small and unreadable on an Iphone safari browser. I want the size to be bigger with a bigger font, so that we can read it.
Any suggestions or solutions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not just direct them to the maps application?

Comment: @RichardJ.Ross Could you please elaborate more about that? Redirect to what map application?

Comment: the built in application? How much clearer can I get?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics)

Answer (score 0):

Well you are going to want to check if it is a mobile browser here is a php snippet

```
<?php
if(strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'mobile') || strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'android')) {
 //Style Google Maps Javascript here
} ?>
```

However, I don't think you can change the font size of the labels.